# Why does index map to a single number in a pandas data-frame?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I set the index to a data frame in the following way:

```
df = df.set_index(['i_id', 'o_id', 'p_id'])
```

For most of the indices it works fine. For example:

```
df.ix[df.index[18]]
```

returns

```
                                   val1     val2
i_id     o_id    p_id
39283      81      14               1.0      2.0
```

However, if I use 19 instead of 18 I get just a number:

```
137.99000000000001
```

What could it be? Btw, 20 works fine again.